# Timer for my game isn't cleared when my start screen is triggered

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've created a basic tag game with 2 players, the chaser and the runner (Bob, and Phil). If the chaser and the runner collide or the time reaches 0, the game goes back to the start screen and can be played again if space is pressed. Everything worked until I tried adding upgrades that spawn around the map and when collected, increase the players' speed. The upgrades themselves work but a glitch with the timer at the top of my screen has appeared. Before this, the timer worked perfectly, but now, it isn't cleared when my game restarts and is visible in the start screen. When the game is restarted multiple times (through collisions), the timers overlap. This is a picture of the timer working when played https://prnt.sc/nkuix1. And this is a picture of the glitch https://prnt.sc/nkuj89. As you can see, the timer should have been cleared but that is not the case and the aforementioned overlapping has occurred. I commented out code that is not very relevant to my problem.

```
import turtle
import math
import random

# Distance formula for collision checking
def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if distance < 30:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Makes the wn that the game is played on


def pregame():
    global play
    play = False
    turtle.clearscreen()
    global wn
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.tracer()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.setup(width = 900, height = 900)    
    global start
    start = turtle.Turtle()
    start.speed(0)
    start.color("white")
    start.penup()
    start.goto(0, 0)
    start.write("PRESS SPACE TO START!", False, align='center', font=('Arial Bold', 48, 'normal'))
    start.hideturtle()

    wn.listen()
    wn.onkey(game, "space")

def game():
    global play
    play = True
    start.clear()
    runner = "omright.gif"
    chaser = "pilav angry.gif"
    wn.addshape(chaser)
    wn.addshape(runner)

    #Designs the 4 sides of the game
    border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
    border_pen.speed(0)
    border_pen.color("white")
    border_pen.penup()
    border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
    border_pen.pendown()
    border_pen.pensize(3)
    for side in range(4):
        border_pen.fd(600)
        border_pen.lt(90)
    border_pen.hideturtle()

    seconds = turtle.Turtle()
    seconds.speed(0)
    seconds.color("white")
    seconds.penup()

    global number

    number = turtle.Turtle()
    number.speed(0)
    number.color("white")
    number.penup()

    title = turtle.Turtle()
    title.speed(0)
    title.color("white")
    title.penup()
    title.setpos(0, 325)
    title.write("THE TAG GAME BY OM", False, align = 'center', font=('Impact', 55, 'normal'))
    title.setpos(370, 315)
    title.write("Patent Pending", False, align = 'center', font=('Calibri', 11, 'normal'))
    title.setpos(370, -335)
    title.write("Not Really Pending", False, align = 'center', font=('Calibri', 11, 'normal'))
    title.hideturtle()
    global timer
    timer = 30

    def countdown():
        number.clear()
        global timer
        timer -= 1

        if timer <= 0:
            pregame()
        if timer > 0:
            seconds.goto(0, 270)
            seconds.hideturtle()
            seconds.write('Time Left:', False, align = 'center', font = ('Arial', 14, 'normal'))
            number.goto(60, 270)
            number.write('{}'.format(timer), False, align = 'center', font = ('Arial', 14, 'normal'))
            number.hideturtle()

            wn.ontimer(countdown, 1000)
    wn.ontimer(countdown, 10)

    # # First turtle (basically an object that can be manipulated)
    # bob = turtle.Turtle()
    # bob.speed(0)
    # bob_speed = 20
    # bob.color("blue")
    # bob.penup()
    # bob.setpos(-50, 0)
    # bob.seth(0)
    # bob.shape(chaser)


    # # Function to move first turtle (bob)
    # def fd():
    #   bob.seth(90)
    #   bob.fd(bob_speed)
    #   # Border Checking
    #   if bob.xcor() > 280:
    #       bob.setx(280)
    #   if bob.ycor() > 280:
    #       bob.sety(280)

    #   if bob.xcor() < -280:
    #       bob.setx(-280)
    #   if bob.ycor() < -280:
    #       bob.sety(-280)
    #   # Checks for collision with enemy player
    #   if isCollision(bob, phil):
    #       # If there is collision, resets players'
    #       pregame()

    # # Moves right (90 degrees)
    # def right():
    #   bob.seth(0)
    #   bob.fd(bob_speed)
    #   # Border Checking
    #   if bob.xcor() > 280:
    #       bob.setx(280)
    #   if bob.ycor() > 280:
    #       bob.sety(280)

    #   if bob.xcor() < -280:
    #       bob.setx(-280)
    #   if bob.ycor() < -280:
    #       bob.sety(-280)
    #   # Checks for collision with enemy player
    #   if isCollision(bob, phil):
    #       # If there is collision, resets players'
    #       pregame()

    # # Moves left (90 degrees)
    # def left():
    #   bob.seth(180)
    #   bob.fd(bob_speed)
    #   # Border Checking
    #   if bob.xcor() > 280:
    #       bob.setx(280)
    #   if bob.ycor() > 280:
    #       bob.sety(280)

    #   if bob.xcor() < -280:
    #       bob.setx(-280)
    #   if bob.ycor() < -280:
    #       bob.sety(-280)
    #   # Checks for collision with enemy player
    #   if isCollision(bob, phil):
    #       # If there is collision, resets players'
    #       pregame()
    # def down():
    #   bob.seth(270)
    #   bob.fd(bob_speed)
    #   # Border Checking
    #   if bob.xcor() > 280:
    #       bob.setx(280)
    #   if bob.ycor() > 280:
    #       bob.sety(280)
    #       phil.seth(180)

    #   if bob.xcor() < -280:
    #       bob.setx(-280)
    #   if bob.ycor() <- 280:
    #       bob.sety(-280)
    #   # Checks for collision with enemy player
    #   if isCollision(bob, phil):
    #       # If there is collision, resets players'
    #       pregame()


    # # Second turtle
    # phil = turtle.Turtle()
    # phil.speed(0)
    # phil_speed = 20
    # phil.penup()
    # phil.shape("triangle")
    # phil.color("red")
    # phil.setpos(50, 0)
    # phil.seth(180)
    # phil.shape(runner)

    # #Refer back to first turtle
    # def fdp():
    #   phil.seth(90)
    #   phil.fd(phil_speed)
    #   if phil.xcor() > 280:
    #       phil.setx(280)
    #   if phil.ycor() > 280:
    #       phil.sety(280)

    #   if phil.xcor() < -280:
    #       phil.setx(-280)
    #   if phil.ycor() < -280:
    #       phil.sety(-280)
    #   if isCollision(bob, phil):
    #       pregame()
    # def rightp():
    #   phil.seth(0)
    #   phil.fd(phil_speed)
    #   # Border Checking
    #   if phil.xcor() > 280:
    #       phil.setx(280)
    #   if phil.ycor() > 280:
    #       phil.sety(280)

    #   if phil.xcor() < -280:
    #       phil.setx(-280)
    #   if phil.ycor() < -280:
    #       phil.sety(-280)
    #   # Checks for collision with enemy player
    #   if isCollision(phil, bob):
    #       # If there is collision, resets players'
    #       pregame()


    # def leftp():
    #   phil.seth(180)
    #   phil.fd(phil_speed)
    #   # Border Checking
    #   if phil.xcor() > 280:
    #       phil.setx(280)
    #   if phil.ycor() > 280:
    #       phil.sety(280)

    #   if phil.xcor() < -280:
    #       phil.setx(-280)
    #   if phil.ycor() < -280:
    #       phil.sety(-280)
    #   # Checks for collision with enemy player
    #   if isCollision(phil, bob):
    #       # If there is collision, resets players'
    #       pregame()

    # def downp():
    #   phil.seth(270)
    #   phil.fd(phil_speed)
    #   # Border Checking
    #   if phil.xcor() > 280:
    #       phil.setx(280)
    #   if phil.ycor() > 280:
    #       phil.sety(280)

    #   if phil.xcor() < -280:
    #       phil.setx(-280)
    #   if phil.ycor() < -280:
    #       phil.sety(-280)
    #   # Checks for collision with enemy player
    #   if isCollision(phil, bob):
    #       # If there is collision, resets players'
    #       pregame()


    # # Logs keys and outputs function
    # wn.listen()
    # wn.onkey(left, "Left")
    # wn.onkey(fd, "Up")
    # wn.onkey(right, "Right")
    # wn.onkey(down, "Down")

    # wn.listen()
    # wn.onkey(leftp, "a")
    # wn.onkey(fdp, "w")
    # wn.onkey(rightp, "d")
    # wn.onkey(downp, "s")

    upgrades = []

    for i in range(3):
        upgrade = turtle.Turtle()
        upgrade.speed(0)
        upgrade.color('white')
        upgrade.shape("square")
        upgrade.penup()
        x = random.randint(-300, 300)
        y = random.randint(-300, 300)
        upgrade.sety(y)
        upgrade.setx(x)
        upgrades.append(upgrade)

    while play == True:
        wn.update() 
        for upgrade in upgrades:
            if isCollision(bob, upgrade):
                bob_speed += 5

                x = random.randint(-300, 300)
                y = random.randint(-300, 300)
                upgrade.sety(y)
                upgrade.setx(x)

        for upgrade in upgrades:
            if isCollision(phil, upgrade):
                phil_speed += 5

                x = random.randint(-300, 300)
                y = random.randint(-300, 300)
                upgrade.sety(y)
                upgrade.setx(x)














pregame()

# Stops program from closing automatically when it is run
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring score outside of your function, and use `global score` in each function that references it

```
score = 30

def init():
  global score
  score = 30

def game():
  global score
  score = score + 1

init()
game()
```

Comment: Nope, the timer still appears.